# Why __init__() is missing one required positional argument?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm just reading a book to learn Python, and by trying to code some classes by my own, it results in that error.

I already tried to change some things in the code but nothing seems to help.

```
class Brands:

def __init__(self,name,price):
    self.name = name
    self.price = price

def check_high_price(self):
    if price > 100:
        print("The product has a high price!")


class Razer(Brands):
pass



razer_blackwidow_x_chroma = Razer("Blackwidow X Chroma")
razer_blackwidow_x_chroma_price = Razer(int(120))
print("Product Name: " + razer_blackwidow_x_chroma.name)
print("Product Price: " + razer_blackwidow_x_chroma.price)
```

I just expect it to print the name and price from the product, but it gives me that error: (TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'price')

Comment: `name, price`..

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell python what variable you are assigning.

change

```py
razer_blackwidow_x_chroma = Razer("Blackwidow X Chroma")
razer_blackwidow_x_chroma_price = Razer(int(120))
```

to

```py
razer_blackwidow_x_chroma = Razer(name="Blackwidow X Chroma", price=120)
```

Also you don't really need to use `int()` when working with whole numbers. In python numbers with decimals, ex: `55.6`, are automatically floats and whole numbers, ex: `120`, are integers.

Also, you don't have to use variable names when initiating a class, but it's a pro tip to help stay organized.